# Is one required to tie strong tzitzis knots?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, tying-knots-kosheir

In the comments [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44454/sliding-tzitzis-knot-on-shabbos), you can find several suggestions of how to make sure your tzitzis knots will not loosen.

Is one required to tie their knots this way, to prevent them from coming loose while they aren't paying attention, or coming loose on Shabbos when one cannot fix them?

Comment: It seems the common custom is not to require this.

Comment: @DoubleAA agreed

Comment: Then do you have any reason to suspect it _is_ a requirement?

Comment: @DoubleAA There are _lots_ and _lots_ and _lots_ of things that it is not the common custom but there is a reason why it should be done nonetheless.  I stated my reason for suspecting as much in the question - please let me know if there is anything unclear about it.