# Keeping tzitzit knots from coming undone

Tags: tzitzis, how-to

The last knot on the tzitzit on my talit keep coming loose. I pull the string to tighten the knot, and three days later it starts to unravel again. Any ideas on how I can make the knots stay tight and not loosen?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44454/sliding-tzitzis-knot-on-shabbos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way which works for me is by taking the last knot and dip into hot water ,then I tie it tightly.  I have yet have a knot open.  Simple and easy. Don't know why this isn't more known and implicated in the tzizts factories.

Comment: When I was a bochur in Denver Yeshivah, R' Kagan told us to dip it in hot boiling water as well.

Comment: I dont believe it makes a diff if its boiling or not. I personally just use hot water and it works great.

Comment: +1 works for me with cold water too, but hot water is probably better. I just turn on the tap water, tighten the knot, and stick the knot under the tap.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, tziztit are usually made from wool? The boiling water makes sense, then. Ever notice that when you put a wo0l sweater in the laundry with hot water, it shrinks? There's probably a reason why sheep like to huddle together. Wool makes each other warmer :-)

Comment: Is there a problem with gluing the knots?

Comment: The Shevet Halevi allows it,but I think water is more natural, and there are some who still question the glueing application

Comment: I took your advice a few days before Pesach, and here it is a little after simchat torah and they're still staying put so this advice has survived the test of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If your double knots are frequently slipping open, they might be [granny knots rather than reef knots](http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/grannyknot.htm). That is, if both layers of the double-knot are tied with the same side on top, the knot is much less secure than if one layer has left on top, and the other has right on top. Untying the second layer, switching which set of strings goes over which, and retying may solve your problem.

Comment: +1 I remembered seeing a granny knot discussion here once and couldn't find it again. I see it was that comment of yours on the other question.