# Tzizit knot laws.

Tags: halacha, tzitzis

Can the double knots on tzizit be any kind of knot or only a specific kind of double knot? Are their halachos regulating the knots?

Comment: How many kinds of double knots are there? @msh

Comment: @double AA my point is whats considered a double knot regarding halacha and can you use different kinds. Halacha could define double knot differently than the English language. In fact the English language does seem to define double knit as any knit tied tied twice https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/double-knot

Comment: Does halakha have a category of "double knot"? I've heard of "permanent knot" "artisnal knot" "slip knot" "unprofessional knot" in halakha before. If you have a reason to think halakha recognizes the category "double knot" please add it to the question. If you don't, then just ask about the knots of tzitzit and don't limit to a category that may not exist

Comment: @double Well we have it by Tzizit don't we? And by shabbos I remember learning about double knots and how they're  prohibited מדרייתה.

Comment: I usually see tzitzit tied with double knots. That doesn't mean there is such a category. If you have a reason to think halakha recognizes the category "double knot" please add it to the question. If you don't, then just ask about the knots of tzitzit and don't limit to a category that may not exist. On Shabbat permanent knots of all forms are forbidden

Comment: @DoubleAA Pretty "straightforward" double knots can close up (ie. connecting the loose ends at the top and bottom) to give a square knot or either of the granny knots, which are three topologically distinct knots. Not necessarily halakhically relevant, of course.

Comment: @magi https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90389/759

Comment: See Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chayim 317:1. The discussion in regard to Tzitzit is about permanent knots (קשר קיימא), not double knots (קשר כפולה).

Comment: The gemara and the Mishneh Torah and I believe even the geonim do not mention a double not. They mention the knots of three windings.